# Does MongoDB store any information about document attribute types?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, types

When I attempt to add an index to a collection
`<collection>.createIndex({ reaction: 1, team_id: 1 }, { unique: true })`
I get Error 10088: Cannot index parallel arrays.

But I don't have any arrays in the collection.

When I search attributes with {$type: 'array'} I show zero documents.
When I search for {$type: 'string'} all documents are returned.

Previously these attributes were arrays but since have been converted.
Is mongodb storing attribute type information somewhere?

```
// Original document
{
  "value" : 5,
  "team_id" : ["T024F579X"],
  "reaction" : ["star2"],
}

// new converted document
{
  "value" : 5,
  "team_id" : "T024F579X",
  "reaction" : "star2",
}
```

`mongod version: 3.2.11 (MMAPv1)`
`_id` is the only index on this collection

Comment: Please clarify when/where/how you get that error.

Comment: updated! thank you for the feedback

Comment: Can you also provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Which MongoDB version?

Comment: 3.2.11 is the version

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the answer here would be: No, mongo does not store type information.

Turns out I did have a document with array attributes.
The issues was with how `$type` works.
team_id in `"team_id" : ["T024F579X"],` will be read as type `string` by mongo.

[from the mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

> When applied to arrays, $type matches any inner element

Meaning that only nested arrays will be read as type `array`.

An effective way to query for any existing `top level` arrays in your collection is to use `$size` [Mongo $size docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)